# changing data output with onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an option box which lists the users of something in my site. I then have two input boxes. One for wins and another for losses. I am trying to create an onchange event, so that whenever a certain user is selected from the option box, the php will output that users info. As of now the output is not changing. What am I doing wrong with my onchange event?

```
function myFunction() {
    var wins_var = document.getElementById('wins');
    var losses_var = document.getElementById('losses');
}
```

PHP that outputs the data and html with inputs

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM team_rankings WHERE user_id=user_id")) {

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($ranking_id, $ranking_user_id, $ranking_firstname, $ranking_username, $ranking_division, $ranking_wins, $ranking_losses); 

    //var_dump($stmt);

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }

$stmt->store_result();
    echo "<select name = 'member' onchange='myFunction()'>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    echo "<option value = '{$ranking_user_id}' data-wins = '{$ranking_wins}' data-losses = '{$ranking_losses}'";
    echo ">{$ranking_firstname}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";


    }   else {
        echo "<p>There are not any team players yet.</p>";
        }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}?><br><br>

        <label>Wins
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ranking_wins; ?>" id="win">
        </label>
        <label>Loss
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ranking_losses; ?>" id="losse">
        </label>
```

Comment: Your tag says you are using ajax, where is that script?

Comment: I didn't know if Ajax would help. I am completely new to javascript. I thought an onchange event would make this work alone.

Comment: Well the `onchange` only triggers the event, then in your function you have the ajax. jQuery is probably the most straight-forward.

Comment: How could I go about it?

Comment: Basicly what you want to do is send out data with Ajax to your php script. Php can then echo the requested data back to your Ajax call which in turn will update your website with the required information. In short: `Ajax sends username to PHP -> PHP queries database for info -> PHP echos result back to Ajax -> Ajax updates the website with the result.`

Comment: There are a lot of examples of AJAX out there on google. You will probably find a lot are on this site when you search.

Comment: Does it need to be done with AJAX?

Comment: It doesn't have to. You could simply query all user info, put it in some tables or divs, mark invisible with CSS and only make one visible with an onclick event. It would however become quite a messy code. Ajax is definitely preferred.

Comment: Unfortunetely I can't give you a good example here as it wouldn't be an answer to your question. If however you require more in dept help on creating this, feel free to click my profile and send me an email. Through there I can give you better support then here due to SO rules.

Comment: @icecub I sent you an email. I definitely want to learn this as I will be using it a lot in the future I believe.

Comment: I've given you a reply. If you rly want to learn this, I think it's best we meet up on SO chat. Having a live form of communication would be most beneficial.

Comment: Though in this case it's a bit annoying as it requires a certain amount of comments before a question can be opened up to a chat.

Comment: Yea that would be great. I will be home shortly and would love to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86739/discussion-between-icecub-and-becky).

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right lines, and you don't need to do any Ajax just to achieve what you asked in your question.

The main problem is that in your Javascript, you get a reference to the two inputs for wins and losses, but you don't actually assign any value to them.

Assuming you're using jQuery (as you tagged it), then it's much easier to use this for the onchange binding and value assignments.

Firstly, you just need to make sure your "member" select has an ID instead (or as well) as a name, and you don't need the "onchange" as we'll bind that with jQuery:

```
echo "<select id = 'member'>";
```

Then, your Javascript just needs to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#member").change(function() {
        myFunction();
   });
   myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
       $selectedOption = $("#member option:selected");
       $("#wins").val($selectedOption.data("wins"));
       $("#losses").val($selectedOption.data("losses"));    
}
```

The initial `$(document).ready()` function sets up the onchange binding to call `myFunction()`, and the second `myFunction()` call just ensures the wins and losses inputs are populated for the default selected option on the initial page load.

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fa0kdox7/

Oh yes, and finally, your wins and losses inputs just need to look like this:

```
<label>Wins
    <input type="text" value="" id="wins">
</label>
<label>Loss
    <input type="text" value="" id="losses">
</label>
```

Note that I corrected a couple of typos in their IDs.